# GCC optimization bug on weak const variable

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, constants, weak

I'm getting a weird `gcc` behaviour when dealing with **weak const variables** on different optimize levels (i.e. `-O0` or `-O1`).

Here is the code:

**def.h**: declarations

```c
const int var;
int copy;
int do_copy(void);
```

**weak.c**: weak `var` definition, `do_copy` implementation doing `copy = var`

```c
#include "def.h"
const int __attribute__((weak)) var = 1;
int do_copy(void)
{
    copy = var;
    return var;
}
```

**main.c**: strong `var` definition, and use of `do_copy`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "def.h"
int copy = 0;
int copy2 = 0;
const int var = 2;
int main(void)
{
    copy2 = do_copy();
    printf("copy=%d, copy2=%d\n", copy, copy2);
    return 0;
}
```

From this 'main.c' code, I am expecting both `copy` and `copy2` to retain the strong `var` value, being `2`.

Here is the output with a **`-O0` optimization**:

```sh
$ gcc -O0 -c main.c -o main0.o
$ gcc -O0 -c weak.c -o weak0.o
$ gcc main0.o weak0.o -o main0
$ ./main0
copy=2, copy2=2
```

This is the expected result.

Here is the output with a **`-O1` optimization**:

```sh
$ gcc -O1 -c main.c -o main1.o
$ gcc -O1 -c weak.c -o weak1.o
$ gcc main1.o weak1.o -o main1
$ ./main1
copy=1, copy2=2
```

This is **unexpected**: while `copy2` does retain the strong value (`2`), `copy` is actually set to the weak value (`1`)!

Within the 'weak.c' file, it looks like `var` is always evaluated to `1`.
My take is that as `var` is declared `const`, the compiler thinks that its value will always be `1` and does this optimization on the whole file (except for the `return` statement). Hence, it misses the weak/strong thing, and does not care about the strong redefinition in 'main.c'!

The issue can be solved by :

- setting the weak definition (`const int __attribute__((weak)) var = 1;`) in a separate file, say 'weak2.c'.
- not making `var` constant (*which might not be acceptable!*): `const int var;` ---> `int var;`.

Still, this looks like a `gcc` bug to me, but am I missing something?

**Appendix:**

This is the used version of `gcc`:

```sh
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [GCC weak attribute on constant variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087831).

Comment: @IanAbbott Indeed, it looks like the same issue. But it does not mention the optimization level effect.

Comment: The GCC online documentation doesn't say a lot about it.

Comment: What stops you from making a bug report to GCC?

Comment: I get `copy=1, copy2=1` with `-O1` with `gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0` on AMD64.

Comment: I get exactly the same behaviour with clang.

Comment: Possible workaround: When i replace `-O1` with the individual optimizations options that are enabled by `-O1`, i get `copy=2, copy2=2`, no idea why.

Comment: Dubplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177223/gcc-o2-and-attribute-weak